# One freewheeling diode for two relays?

Tags: diodes, circuit-design, relay

I have two separate relays, both with different part numbers and coil inductances. Both are driven with the same 12V 'control signal.' When the control signal is removed, the inductance of both coils would try to resist the change in current by generating a voltage on the negative side and the free wheeling diode gives this voltage a path.

In such a case you'd have two different voltages generated as a function of the inductance of the two coils. These will superimpose into an even larger voltage.
Provided I use a diode rated for the coil currents flowing through the combination of the two should I just use one diode, or is it still good practice to use two? The only thing I can think of is that the layout path would now be longer if one diode is used and therefore larger voltage loop/EMI concern.